# Where have I gone wrong here? system of 5 equations from lagrange multipliers (2 constraints)

Tags: systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to find extrema for $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ with 2 constraints:

$$x^2-y^2=1 \\
2x+z=1$$

So I'll say that $g(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2$ and $h(x,y,z)=2x+z$. So I'll try to find values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$ when:

$$\nabla f=\lambda . \nabla g + \mu . \nabla h$$

Taking the gradients of the 3 functions, I have:
$$\nabla f= \langle 1;1;1\rangle\\
\nabla g=\langle 2x; -2y; 0\rangle \\
\nabla h=\langle 2;0;1\rangle 
$$

So this leaves me with the following 5 equations (3 from the multiplier definition and 2 from the restrictions):

$$\begin{cases}
1=2x\lambda+2\mu \\
1=-2y\lambda \\
1= \mu\\
1= x^2-y^2\\
1= 2x+z\\
\end{cases}
$$

I started solving the first as $x=\frac{-1}{2 \lambda}$ and then the second as $y=\frac{-1}{2 \lambda}$ (I purposely avoided dividing both terms by $x$ or $y$ because I don't know if any of them are 0).

However, since now $x$ and $y$ have the same value, if I plug it in the fourth equation: $1= x^2-y^2$ I get that $1=0$.

What have I done wrong? And how could I solve an equation for $\lambda$, when I still don't know if $x$ or $y$ are $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a mistake. It is just that the extrema do not exist. Consider:

$x = \sqrt{1 + y^2}$, $z = 1 - 2x$, then $x + y + z = x + y + 1 - 2x = 1 + y - x = 1 + y - \sqrt{1 + y^2}$. Differentiating wrt $y$, and equating to 0 gives $y = \sqrt{1 + y^2}$, which obviously has no solutions.

Comment: @RajatMittal Of course, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)  Let me see if I understand the reasoning: First you did some composition of $f(x,y,z)$ with the constraints, right? Is it because we need to find a common point (or points) where all 3 functions meet? And then why did you take the derivative with respect to $y$ and equate that to $0$? Thanks again :)